# Use embed URL from proxy with php

Tags: php, proxy

I have several iframes on my site and I would like to know if it's possible to read content from a specific URL from a free proxy service.

**Something like this:**

```
$url = '/https://www.example.com/embed/content';
$proxy_and_port = '103.326.255.299:3128';
$url_by_proxy =  $proxy_and_port . $url;

<iframe src="http://<?php echo $url_by_proxy;?>" width=300 height=250></iframe>
```

Comment: Does it seem to work?

Comment: @showdev nop, already tried without success